# Avoiding multiple calls to observable$ | async in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my component, I have injected a service that provides the current language as an observable. In that component template, I'm displaying prices several times based upon the user's locale, in this manner:

`<p>{{price.toLocaleString(languageService.getCurrentLanguage() | async, { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })}}</p>`

The issue is that I have like 10 `async` calls all over my template, and even though `languageService` actually returns the subject as a shared observable, effectively creating one shared stream instead of a different stream every time the `async` pipe subscribes, I'm willing to believe there's a better way to do this out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the observable to a field and bind to that field instead:

```
<p>{{price.toLocaleString(currentLanguage() | async, { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })}}</p>
```

```
constructor(languageService:LanguageService) {
 this.currentLanguage = languageService.getCurrentLanguage();
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but in this case, what do I gain except for brevity?

Comment: That `getCurrentLanguage()` is only called once.

Comment: Alright, I'll buy that :D
In this case, do you think it would be worth writing a pipe to do the entire `.toLocaleString` call in one shot?

Comment: Injecting the `LanguageService` into the pipe won't work, because the pipe only updates when the value passed to the pipe or a parameter changes. So if you inject the service to the pipe and the service emits a new value, nothing will happen. Is this what you meant?